# How to create a field validation function

Tags: visual-workflow

I'm a newbie to SF Flow (but not to SF).

I have several objects with one or more field(s) which should only have a certain list of values.

I would like to create a 'triggered upon record create/update' flow for each object which validates the field(s) and then ...

Naively, I'd want to create/use something like 'isValidXXX(<field_value>)' which can be used as needed.

After doing some reading, I get the impression that I'd need to create an Apex Class to do this.

Is this correct or am I missing something ?

TIA

Comment: This sounds like you should be using a picklist (and mark it as being "restricted" so that only the active values for the picklist are allowed) rather than trying to create a flow or a validation rule. Is there a reason why you're not going that route?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour]. Please [edit] your post to include more detail and an example.  As Derek mentions, you may need just a restricted picklist rather than a Flow.

Comment: The specific problem is that a 3rd party App (sometimes/always) when creating a record is putting a full state name (e.g.: 'New Jersey'') in certain fields.

Comment: They should fix this but it seems this isn't going to happen. So, I want to add a kludge to convert the state name to the two letter abbreviation as needed.

Comment: Use a before save flow to convert the value `New Jersey` to `NJ`; extend for other states/provinces. You can set up the mappings in CMDT or a custom object